# Node.js file upload not working

Tags: node.js, dotcloud

I'm building a super simple file server with node.js.

I'm using dotcloud to host my server, which is [accessible here.](http://fileserve-todd_davies.dotcloud.com/upload)

When I try to upload a file (with the correct password), my code returns `'Error, incorrect password!'`. Take a look at the code below, and I'll explain why:

```js
var success = false;
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(err,fields, files) {
            console.log("Password: " + fields.password);
    if(fields.password!="poop") {
        return;
    }
       fs.rename(files.upload.path, files.upload.name, function (err) {  });
       success = true;
          res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
          res.write('received upload:\n\n');
          res.end();
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
          // empty 200 OK response for now
      if(success) {
              res.writeHead(302, { 'location': '/' });
          } else {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
              res.write('Error, incorrect password!\n');
      }
          res.end();
        });
```

I think my code is failing at 'fs.rename(files.....)' as then the success variable isn't set to true. My code works on my local node.js installation, do I need to request write permissions from dotcloud or something?

Comment: P.S. I'm using formidable to do my uploading.

Comment: yes, you need to request write permissions from dotcloud, if the node app is writing to the host system

Comment: How do I do that? Thanks for a quick reply!

Comment: How do I request write permissions from dotcloud?

Comment: I don't know that that's the actual problem, but are you asking how to get customer service from the company you're paying monthly?

Comment: No, I have a free account limited to two services. I haven't consciously asked for write permissions and can't find how to do so!

Comment: You could try answers.dotcloud.com or support.dotcloud.com for support. You could also check this out: http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/s3fs/ it shows you how to store your uploaded files to s3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `end` event for the HTTP request is emitted *before* formidable parses the form.

The exact order of event dispatch is not defined in the Node.js documentation; so it could be that depending on the Node.js version and/or platform, they end up being processed in different orders.

In that case, if that happens, `success` is then `false` and you send the reply before even actually parsing the form.

Maybe you should handle errors in the form parsing function instead?